# Push Notification not showing in IOS

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, push-notification

I am using Firebase Cloud Messaging to send push notifications.

```
    _firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions();
    _firebaseMessaging.subscribeToTopic('all');
    _firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((value) => print(value));
    _firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print('onMessage');
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print('onResume');
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print('onLaunch');
      },
    );
```

It is working on android. However, i do not get notification on IOS.
It shows the notification permission request and does print the token.
IOS-specific configurations are also done.
In my apple developer account, I created the key and identifier and downloaded the certificate and uploaded it to firebase.
I have also added the `push notification` and `background modes` capabilities from xCode.

I get no Error, neither I receive the notification.

Comment: did you solve this?